# SQL not ran by JDBC but perfectly functional in Database Clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a query to select tree structure data from SQL Server 2012 to fetch tree structured resultset from one table.

This is the SQL I used:

```
with cte_child (id, parentId, contractId, contractName, jfCompany, jfDepartment, yfDepartment, totalAmount, signDate, lvl)
as 
(
    select 
        id, parentId, contractId, contractName, 
        jfCompany, jfDepartment, yfDepartment, totalAmount, signDate, 0
    from 
        Contract_info_main
    where 
        contractId = 'c2012-0412'

    union all

    select 
        c.id, c.parentId, c.contractId, c.contractName, 
        c.jfCompany, c.jfDepartment, c.yfDepartment, c.totalAmount, 
        c.signDate, s.lvl+1
    from 
        Contract_info_main c
    inner join 
        cte_child s on s.parentId = c.id
)
select * from cte_child
```

This SQL statement does run with correct result on local SQL Server 2012 database, as well as my local machine with DBeaver client. The driver used by DBeaver is "mssql-jdbc:7.4.1.jre8".

The weird thing is when I use pure Java code to send identical SQL string to send exactly same query, it fails with an error

> object name 'Contract_inf_main' is invalid

Since I am using Ubuntu 18, I guess DLL along with Driver should not be a problem? but what could be possible cause of this problem? thanks

This is my JDBC code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.5.158:1433", "general_reader", "sqlserver2017@reader");

    final String sql = "with cte_child(id, parentId, contractId, contractName, jfCompany, jfDepartment, yfDepartment, totalAmount, signDate, lvl) " +
                               "as (select id, parentId, contractId, contractName, jfCompany, jfDepartment, yfDepartment, totalAmount, signDate, 0 " +
                               "from Contract_info_main where contractId = 'jy2012-041' " +
                               "union all select c.id, c.parentId, c.contractId, c.contractName, c.jfCompany, c.jfDepartment, c.yfDepartment, c.totalAmount, c.signDate, s.lvl+1 " +
                               "from Contract_info_main c inner join cte_child s on s.parentId = c.id) select * from cte_child";

    final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    System.out.println(sql);

    final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("id = " + resultSet.getString(1) + " and parentId = " + resultSet.getString(2));
    }

    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you share the code that does not work ?

Comment: @VBoka Sorry I forgot to provide code. the sql printed on console is working in clients

Comment: You are probably connecting to a different database in SSMS. Your JDBC URL does not specify a database, so you are relying on the default database for the user `general_reader` which might be different or not assigned at all

Comment: What's the full and complete error message you get, because none of your SQL includes `Contract_inf_main`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right, the catalog of the Connection is not set. I am used thanks for the hint. now the problem solved.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning a_house_with_no_name get the actual cause of the problem. catalog of the connection must be set, otherwise the default scheme is not my targer one. thanks anyway